# Why need first save to Files then to Photos?

Tags: iphone, icloud, photos

I have this image: http://t44-post-cover.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/bixw.mp4

When it is loaded to browser on an iPhone, I can not download directly to Photos, it is not among sharing options, but first I need to save into Files then to Photos. Why? Is it any workaround for it?

Comment: How does this differ from https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/451018/why-ios-not-offer-the-ability-for-certain-videos-to-save-video-to-camera-roll ?

Comment: As it turned out it is possible to save photo to Photos, but through Files. I am curious why, and why not save directly.

Comment: An MP4 file is not an image.

Comment: Yes, it is not, but usually videos and images are treated identically